# Persistent Shopping Cart Issue with customer groups

Tags: shopping-cart, persistent

I'm running into an issue with persistent shopping carts and customers from a certain customer group.

Here's the scenario:

A customer tagged to my wholesale customer group logs into the website, they then see their special pricing due to their customer group. The customer then logs out of the website (at that point it leaves the **"WELCOME, *USER* *NAME*! (NOT *USER* *NAME*?)**, obviously with the actual customer name in the place of USER NAME). The customer then comes back to the website and sees their name in the top of the screen and their special pricing. They then continue to shop and checkout. When they go to checkout, if they don't login, it processes them as a normal not-logged in customer.

I'm using the one-step-checkout from http://magestore.com, so the customer doesn't see the login prompt immediately like they do with the default Magento one page checkout.

Is there anyway to fix this? Essentially, I want to know if there's a way to do away with the "not customer name" block at the top of the screen, regardless of customer level.

This block is labeled mage_persistent_lock_header_additional and it's a core file, so I'm hesitant to edit `frontend/base/default/template/core/link.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the persistent checkout functionality in its entirety. There is also a setting I believe to force customers to log in before they can checkout, but this might be One Page Checkout only (not OSC).